# Matlab regex if statement

Tags: regex, matlab, if-statement

I want to have matlab take user input but accept both cases of a letter. For example I have:

```
function nothing = checkGC(gcfile)
if exist(gcfile)
    reply = input('file exists, would you like to overwrite? [Y/N]: ', 's');
    if (reply == [Yy])
        display('You have chosen to overwrite!')
    else
        $ Do nothing
    end
end
```

The if statement obviously doesn't work, but basically I want to accept a lowercase or uppcase Y. Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use the functions [lower](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/lower.html) or [upper](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/upper.html). E.g.:

```
if (lower(reply) == 'y')
```

Alternatively, [strcmpi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strcmpi.html) will compare strings case-insensitively. E.g.:

```
if (strcmpi(reply, 'y'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a basic **or** operator in your condition. Check the documentation here:
http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html

```
if (regexpi(reply,'^y(es)?$'))
        display('You have chosen to overwrite!')
```